# Centos static route

Tags: linux, centos, networking, routing

I have a load generator running on a Centos client and I need to alter the routing table on that client to send all traffic destined to a particular server(192.168.7.215) through a WAN emulator(192.168.7.188).  Following some online reference material, I created a route-eth0 file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts with the line

```
192.168.7.215 via 192.168.7.188 dev eth0
```

and issued command: service network restart

But traffic on the CentoOS client intended for .215 is not going through the WAN emulator.

ip route show:

```
192.168.7.215 via 192.168.7.188 dev eth0
192.168.7.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.7.215
169...(not shown)
default via 192.168.7.1 dev eth0
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Is your WAN emulator on eth0?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The WAN emulator is on the same subnet and has only two interfaces lo and eth0